# Jsoup вычленение куска

Tags: jsoup, html, java

```
имеется примерно следующий вид хтмл
<table>
    <tr>
      <td>text</td>
      <td>text</td>
      <td>text</td>
    </tr>
</table>
<table>
    <tr>
      <td>text</td>
      <td>text</td>
      <td>text</td>
    </tr>
</table>
<table>
    <tr>
      <td>text</td>
      <td>text</td>
      <td>text</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Как выбрать только 3ю таблицу?

Comment: table:eq(2)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

JSoup использует CSS селекторы, поэтому так:

```
table:nth-child(3)
```

ЗЫ http://try.jsoup.org/